# Angular Dynamic Add rows with custom components

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to add rows for search/filter requirement. There are 100s of fields to filter. Do my boss decided to keep them in a dropdown (here in this example I kept Manager, City and Name). When user selects one from the drop down, (lets say, City), the next box should display another drop down with all cities. If user selects Name, the next box should display a Text Box. And user can add as many rows (filters).

I tried and was able to dynamic add rows and display text box or drop down (based on inputType). But my problem is when I change from manager to Name, then it changes all boxes in right side to Text box. And when Add a new row/filer, it automatically displays previous selected drop down or Test. That means what I want is the right side dropdown or text box should appear only when user selects a value from the left side.

I am not sure I am explaining it well or not. But please feel free to ask questions.

Below is the example I have done so far. Thanks in advance for your help! [image]

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-mxdu9f)

[AFTER MAKING CHANGES AS PER BELOW ANSWER] Thanks to @Nick Felker for quick answer.

Now I am able to add and delete rows. I want o get the key/value pair in JSON format. I am getting. but not getting the selected values fro the drop down fields. I am adding a new image and new stackblitz

Any help please.

[image: New Image after below answer]
[New Stackblitz after below answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-zbesps?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is split up the filtering into individual `filter-row-selector` components. That way each selector itself won't affect the others.
I think this demo is closer to what you want: https://angular-mat-select-example-rj86ng.stackblitz.io

`filter-row-selector.component.ts`

```
import { AdvanceFilterFieldsModel } from '../advance.filter.fields.model';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'filter-row-selector',
  templateUrl: './filter-row-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-row-selector.component.css'],
})
export class FilterRowSelectorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('field') field: any;
  advanceFilterFieldsModel: AdvanceFilterFieldsModel[] = [
    { name: 'Manager', value: 'Manager', inputType: 1 },
    { name: 'State', value: 'State', inputType: 1 },
    { name: 'Name', value: 'Name', inputType: 2 },
  ];

  filterPlaceHolerArray: Array<any> = [{}];
  managerArray: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'Manager 1', value: 'Manager1' },
    { name: 'Manager 2', value: 'Manager2' },
    { name: 'Manager 3', value: 'Manager3' },
  ];

  stateArray: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'Alabama', value: 'AL' },
    { name: 'Alaska', value: 'AA' },
    { name: 'Florida', value: 'FL' },
  ];

  displayTextboxFieldValue: boolean = false;
  displaySelectboxFieldValue: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  populateFieldValue(value: any) {
    console.log(value);
    if (value.name == 'Manager') {
      this.filterPlaceHolerArray = this.managerArray;
    } else if (value.name == 'State') {
      this.filterPlaceHolerArray = this.stateArray;
    }
    if (value.inputType == 1) {
      this.displaySelectboxFieldValue = true;
      this.displayTextboxFieldValue = false;
    } else if (value.inputType == 2) {
      this.displayTextboxFieldValue = true;
      this.displaySelectboxFieldValue = false;
    }
  }
}
```

`filter-row-selector.component.html`

```
<td>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)" class="input-group-text">
        <i class="mdi mdi-close mdi-18px"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <mat-select
      (valueChange)="populateFieldValue($event)"
      [(ngModel)]="field.name"
      placeholder="Select"
      appearance="outline"
      style="width: 75% !important; border-bottom-style: ridge !important;"
    >
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let filterField of advanceFilterFieldsModel"
        [value]="filterField"
      >
        {{ filterField.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <input
    *ngIf="displayTextboxFieldValue"
    [(ngModel)]="field.value"
    class="form-control"
    type="text"
    name="{{ fieldName }}"
    placeholder="{{ fieldName }}"
  />
  <mat-select
    *ngIf="displaySelectboxFieldValue"
    placeholder="Select"
    appearance="outline"
    style="width: 500% !important; border-bottom-style: ridge !important;"
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let filterPlaceHoler of filterPlaceHolerArray"
      [value]="filterPlaceHoler"
    >
      {{ filterPlaceHoler.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, and sorry for latte acceptance, I did try last week and it worked.

Comment: One last help please - How do I get the key value pair in JSON format onClick of 'Search' button? User may select multilpe Manager or Cities.

Comment: I would add some kind of function to get the key and value into `filter-row-selector` and then add [an output function](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) to get the value iteratively.

Comment: I am able to call a parent function and I think I can share data with parent template. I did some changes so user can delete a filter. However I am not getting how to get the key/vaue pair in json format. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-zbesps?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Added my next question in the original question with image. Thanks in advance. I understand if you are busy.

Comment: I got the required output.

Comment: As you pass `fieldArray[i]` to each component, which is an object, you are passing by reference. As such, with [a few small mods](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-yrhxpb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Ffilter-row-selector%2Ffilter-row-selector.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffilter-row-selector%2Ffilter-row-selector.component.html) you are able to write values directly back to the `field` input and they can be reflected in the original array.